# How do you research and list up thinkable encoders and decoders when you build NLP models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I'm a beginner in NLP and deep learning fields, and have stacked with the phase how research and list up available and substitutional encoders and decoders.

For example, I read a thesis that Bidirectional `LSTM` and `CRF` were selected for named-entity recognition, like below.

[Named entity recognition with bidirectional lstm+CRF (with tensorflow code) - NER](https://www.programmersought.com/article/7825966810/)

However, if my dataset and these encoders and decoders didn't show high performance, I need to try other encoders and decoders.

My question is:

*When you have the specific NLP task, like `NER`, and dataset to train,
**how do you research applicable encoders and decoders?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no universal solution for that. But I can explain my roadmap as NLP scientist. Firstly, I try to find the most common dataset for my task (NER in your case). Then, I search for the leaderboard which shows the best papers/models for that dataset. Finally, I try to figure out which makes their models best in the leaderboard. For example, here is the text summarization leaderboard: http://nlpprogress.com/english/summarization.html

I hope it is helpful for you.